# Making changes to Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Chrome Devtools's has some some undesirable behaviours regarding to css sourcemaps like in this link https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=257778.

Is it possible to edit Devtools's itself (like Style Panel) so I can do things like directing sourcemap links to open them in editor or prevent loss of sourcemaps? I was able to edit Opera's Dragonfly from the local source. Is it possible to make similar changes with Devtools?

Answer (score 1):

You can edit DevTools UI and serve it from local source tree. See [this doc](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/contributing#contributing-to-devtools-source-code) for more details.